# Duende Sofware Backend for Frontend cookie not found on Firefox

Tags: c#, .net, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

I use Duende Software and Backend for Frontend Pattern,

All is well on local with Edge / Chrome / Firefox,

When I deploy my solutions to my server, all is well on Edge / Chrome but for Firefox (111.0 (64 bits)) I have this exception :

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

In the logs, I see it's because I have no cookie :

`.AspNetCore.Correlation.1GVEGnaW7Z81J1EaVhD_zICu3gQNfSktAd9fhpH1tfg' cookie not found.`

The cookie seems to disapear on Firefox.

Here my Program.cs code from my client solution (in fact it's based on the sample from Duende Sofware Github [Quickstarts JS with backend](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/IdentityServer/v6/Quickstarts/6_JS_with_backend)) :

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Duende.Bff.Yarp;
using JavaScriptClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
    .AddBff()
    .AddRemoteApis();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://myIdentityProvider.com";
        options.ClientId = "MyCliendId";
        options.ClientSecret = "MySecret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ResponseMode = "query";
        options.Scope.Add("MyScope");
    });

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseBff();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapBffManagementEndpoints();

    // Uncomment this for Controller support
    //endpoints.MapControllers()
    //    .AsBffApiEndpoint();
    //

    endpoints.MapGet("/local/identity", LocalIdentityHandler)
        .AsBffApiEndpoint();

    endpoints.MapRemoteBffApiEndpoint("/remote", "https://localhost:6001")
        .RequireAccessToken(Duende.Bff.TokenType.User);
});

app.Run();

[Authorize] 
static IResult LocalIdentityHandler(ClaimsPrincipal user, HttpContext context)
{
    var name = user.FindFirst("name")?.Value ?? user.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
    return Results.Json(new { message = "Local API Success!", user = name });
}
```

[Developer Tools Firefox when redirecting to the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXJs1.png)

An example of the URL : https://dev-XXXXXX/signin-oidc?code=88DC10688209D96A964BEC3C5C0E935B375F44E6D6311EC6D04ACFF47C4091CC-1&scope=openid%20profile%20MyScope&state=CfDJ8ESufyjmGeFBgfz5grcuHwKuuygHk3CR2e9tfyvMv_nl8txvzjV1JKDobk3vHAQvheQcvM4luZc4h8gEkWjt-w-EsSBn1AE6fXj3JNtUUY2jwTdLIgexUTdqpIOqGHmQGpr5sHrJC4t_86Af2SFDKqy1sqUPj3Z60VWHS4VLsz0T86TfgSChhyDPZND4XPJ-gCq5oPAeLfzUP37He9atgsdUGCYWuPjLSiWCOfthmIPvwWL4JWzFb_kmfnQRO9aZbjWAEA7m6pFDAZedJbIfLaRmEN09Ukjs9H6RkzSbw8_KGQ9rOpOo2A0LRX5ErN517Ktj8y5QTChXHi2ckwZcUqfs8IGjN_txOq3oZyLCg8kXAFRXGdNEfdEksvR9UQbYGbO3xvZKLuDYFgJwXvwF9bs&session_state=R1sXE2TDTqckzL1VNU9SOkPPUP-U2uJf4amKEWQPTQE.A8F7AA6340E886AC794E6C8011425C18&iss=https%3A%2F%2FmyIdentityProvider.com%3A820

EDIT :
Actually, my server time was 2 hours behind, so the cookie was already expired, it didn't bother Edge or Chrome but Firefox removed the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use HTTPS, because otherwise, important cookies will be blocked due to the samesite attribute we set on cookies nowadays.

In Firefox, to see why Cookies are rejected:

1. Open the Browser Developer Tools (F12)
2. Select the Console tab, and in the console, you should see the reasoning why the cookies were rejected

[image]

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Yes, I fixed but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Does my updated answer help?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the Developer Tools except there is no cookie when I'm redirected to the client.

Comment: I added the screen capture in my first post.

Comment: Do you run multiple instances of the client application?

Comment: No, only one instance for the client.

Comment: I would use a tool like https://www.getfiddler.com/ to examine the requests and explore when the cookies set are lost.

Comment: How are you deploying the application? container? in what service?

Comment: I deploy on IIS, I'm going to check with getfiddler

Comment: Great ! with Fiddler I found, the cookie was expired, it didn't bother Edge and Chrome but Firefox removed the cookie, thanks !

Comment: Glad you found the problem! feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following cookie option:

```cs
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
})
```

There are two interesting points here:

- The .NET stack uses `SameSite=None` cookies by default, whereas the above setting is the most secure option, with best protection against cross site request forgery.
- It also provides a more convenient developer experience. Cookie rules behave the same over both HTTP and HTTPS, so developers run into less confusion.

If you are interested, the [RFC6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/) spec explains more about the same-site behaviours.

Comment: Thanks, I tested that but I still have the same problem on Firefox when I deploy on my server.